# How to count the iterations of arbitrary increments?

Tags: sequences-and-series

**The problem...**
How do I count how many iterations are between "a" and "bbb" if I keep incrementing the letters?
By incrementing, I mean sequencing in this manner:
a, b, c, ...., y, z, aa, ab, ac, ...., bbb
I'd like to "calculate" how many items are in that sequence.

**How I came about this problem...**
The Chrome's Keyboard Navigation extension produces keyboard shortcuts for all links on the current page.  It assigns the keyboard shortcuts in the same way I described above.
One long page reached the shortcut "bbb" and just started wondering how many links that would be, and was unable to come up with a mathematical way to solve it.
So I wrote a quick program and found the answer is 1,405 iterations.
But surely math can answer faster than writing code for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post consists of three parts: A) a slow but steady way to do the calculation; B)  a demonstration of how the idea of base $26$ representation of numbers can be used to speed up the calculation; C) an introduction to  a modified notion of representation that gives an instant answer and will, we hope, befun to think about.

**A) Slow but Steady:**  There are $26$ $1$-letter "words."

How many $2$-letter words are there?  The first letter of a $2$-letter word can be chosen in $26$ ways.  For **each** of these ways, the second letter can be chosen in $26$ ways, for a total of $26^2$.  (If $26$ women each have $26$ children, then the total number of children is $26^2$.)

The same idea shows that there are $26^3$ $3$ letter words, $26^4$ $4$-letter words, and so on.

However, we don't even want to count all the $3$-letter words, only those up to $bbb$.

How many $3$-letter words start with $a$? We can complete $a$ to a $3$-letter word by appending to $a$ any $2$-letter word. There are $26^2$ such $2$-letter words. So $26^2$ $2$-letter words start with $a$.

Finally, we want to count the $3$-letter words that start with $b$, but we only want to get to $bbb$.  So append any $2$-letter word that starts with $a$
(there are $26$ of these), and finally at the very end we must not forget about $bba$ and $bbb$ (2 words).

Add up. We get $1406$. But probably you did not intend to count the first word, just the "iterations" or "increments."
There are $1405$ of these.

**B) Using Base 26 Representation:** 
 The $1$-letter words were easy to count, as were the $2$-letter words.  The $3$-letter words were a bit of a nuisance, since we did not have a "full set." And we were lucky that the end  was at $bbb$.

If you know representing numbers to different bases, there is a neat way of counting the $3$-letter part.

Think of representing a number to the base $26$. Use $a$ to represent the digit we usually call $0$, $b$ to represent the digit we usually call  $1$, $c$ to represent the digit we usually call $2$, and so on.

(This is not so far-fetched.  When we use base $16$ (hexadecimal) we use the "digits" $0$, $1$, $\dots$, 9, A, B, C, D, E, and F.  Here instead of recycling some of the old standard digits, we are using new symbols for "digits" from the beginning.)

We show that there is a close connection between numbers to the base $26$ and our $3$-letter words.

Let's first think in terms of ordinary base $10$ representation of numbers from $0$ to $999$.  Most of them have $3$ digits, but the small ones have fewer.  It is convenient to "pad" the short ones with initial $0$'s, so that each has $3$ digits.  Thus seven would be represented as $007$.

Use the same convention with base $26$.  So the $3$-letter words can be thought of as base $26$ numbers from $0$ to $26^3-1$. 
 With this convention, the words $aaa$ to $bbb$ represent all numbers from $0$ to "$bbb$". But $bbb$ is
$$1 \times (26)^2+1\times(26)^1+ 1\times (26)^0,$$
which, in decimal, is $703$.  And there are $704$ numbers from $0$ to $703$.

Thus the total number of words is 
$$26 +26^2 +704.$$
Calculate. We get $1406$. To get the number of steps, we subtract $1$.

There is a way to short-circuit the computation even further, since the $26+26^2$ part, and the $1$ that we added to $703$,   can be incorporated into the last part of the calculation.

To see how, note that $26^2+26+1$ is just $bbb$ in base $26$. So all we need to do is add $bbb$ to $bbb$, and evaluate.  Unfortunately, $bbb$ occurs twice here, with different roles. So let's do another example, and ask how many words there are from $a$ to $dgc$, inclusive.  To get the answer, just find $bbb+dgc$
Note that $bbb+dgc=ehd$, and evaluate.  Or else, do the same thing more slowly:

$d$ represents $3$. Add $1$ to this, getting $4$;

$g$ represents $6$. Add $1$ to this, getting $7$;

$c$ represents $2$. Add $1$ to this, getting $3$.

The total is then $4 \times 26^2+7\times 26^1 +3\times 26^0$.

**Exactly** the same basic idea  can be used to solve any problem of this general kind, over any alphabet, and up toa ny specified word, however long.  It comes down to a mechanical one-line computation.

**Using Modified Base $26$ Representation:** Probably not a lot of people care about base $26$ representation, modified or not. So we use this opportunity to write about what we will call modified base $10$ representation.

Imagine a society which has a horror of zero, because it reminds them of hunger, or the great void, or whatever. Let's see how we can modify our usual base $10$ positional notation to suit their needs.

The idea is simple. We will use digits $1$, $2$, $3$, $\dots$, $9$ as usual, and introduce a new digit $x$ to stand for ten.  Now a $4$-digit number like $25x8$ stands for $2 \times 10^3+5\times 10^2 +10\times 10^1 +8 \times 10^0$.

Let's practice counting in modified decimal. Here goes, to one hundred and one.

$$1, 2, \dots, 9, x, 11, 12, \dots, 19, 1x, 21, 22, \dots, 2x, \dots, 89, 8x, 91, \dots, 99, 9x, x1$$

Easy! And arithmetic, once you get used to it, is no harder than in conventional decimal.

We can similarly think of modified base $26$, with $a$ for $1$, $b$ for $2$, and so on up to $z$ for $26$.  The crucial fact is that the number of words of length from $1$ to $k$, up to any $k$-letter word $W$, is just the value of $W$ when it is thought of as a modified base $26$ number. This is because these words are just the names, in order, of the numbers from $1$ to the value of $W$.

Thus the number of such words can be evaluated in one short line.

Comment: If $a$ represents digit zero, then $s$ and $as$ and $aas$ are the same number?

Comment: Brilliant!
When you had the step-by-step solution up, I was like "cool, that makes sense" but was waiting for the base-26 approach.  As soon as you did that, I slapped the ACCEPT button!
10^5 thanks!

Comment: @GEdgar: Again, thanks for pointing out my earlier egregious blunder. Have added a last section giving a bijective argument, without calling it that.